# std::array - 'buffer of size n will be overrun', only in VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

```
constexpr auto CHUNKS_X = 5, CHUNKS_Y = 5, CHUNKS_Z = 1;
std::array<std::bitset<CHUNKS_X>, CHUNKS_Y> ys;
std::array<decltype(ys), CHUNKS_Z> zs;
if (CHUNKS_Z > 1)
{
    zs[0] = ys;
    //zs.at(1) = ys; //this works
    zs[1] = ys; //this doesn't work
    for (auto &x : zs[1])
    {
        x.flip();
    }
    for (auto z = 2; z < CHUNKS_Z; z++)
    {
        zs[z] = zs[z - 2];
    }
}
```

The line `zs[1] = ys;` gives me

```
error C4789: buffer 'zs' of size 20 bytes will be overrun; 20 bytes will be written starting at offset 20
```

But only when compiling in VS. Compiling on the command line gives me no such error, nor does using `zs.at(1) = ys;` instead. Another thing of note is that MSDN says that this should be a warning, not an error.

I realize this might be a subtle compiler flag issue but I haven't the slightest clue where to start looking.

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23506 for x86
```

Comment: What's with the `if (CHUNKS_Z > 1)` this is always false

Comment: @ZivS Those constants are off in another file that someone else might change.

Comment: So, what exactly is your problem?  That line of code would overrun the end of a buffer.  The error looks useful.  As an aside, you might want to generate a [mcve], as I doubt `bitset` is required to generate your problem (as an example).

Comment: @Yakk It wouldn't because `zs[1] = ys` only runs when `zs.size() >= 2`.

Comment: @Sarvadi Yes, but compilers are not required to determine which lines are reachable and which not; this is in general impossible.  The array has a fixed size.  That line, given the fixed size, is an error.

Comment: @Yakk And `operator[]` doesn't do bounds checking, but it gives me an error. Yet `.at()` does bounds checking and gives no error. This might be working as intended, but if that's the case, it certainly doesn't follow general expectations.

Comment: @sarv `.at` is permitted to pass an out if bounds value.  It then throws.  `[]` it is an error to oass an out of bounds value; the compiler can do anything.  In this case, the compiler is failing to compile the code, because it can confirm the error that early.  I suspect UB can time travel even that much (from an unexecuted branch), but am uncertain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::array<decltype(ys), CHUNKS_Z> zs;
```

is equivalent to

```
std::array<decltype(ys), 1> zs;
```

meaning zs is an array with 1 element;

arrays in general are zero-based meaning the first element is at `zs[0]`, and there are no more elements so `zs[1]` requires  that the arrays will have a second element which it doesn't in your example.

Since you check `if (CHUNKS_Z > 1)` there should not be any problem since you can't reach the line `zs[1] = ys;` and you won't get any issues.

If I change `CHUNKS_Z` to `2` I don't get any errors in VS15

Comment: Well, that was a lot simpler than I thought it would be. Still doesn't explain why I don't get this error when compiling on the command line though.